# Scrape off the painting of bathroom celling

Tags: painting

When trying to scrape off the original paint of my bathroom ceiling,I found some areas are quite hard to be scraped off by using the scrapper. I guess it is caused by the moisture or the previous painter applied flat paints straight onto bare gyprock without primer.

You can see on attached photo, the underneath brown paper is shown after I scrapped paint. Did anyone come across this situation? and is there any ways to scrape without damage the gyprock?

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: Why are you scraping the paint off? If there are parts peeling/flaking then scrape off the bad parts. Otherwise, sand it smooth and be done. Scraping works well on wood & brick - not so much of drywall. In any case, with that much scraping if the building dates back to 1978 or earlier, take lead paint precautions.

Comment: Thank you, @manassehkatz-ReinstateMonica. Because most of ceiling areas are covered with mold. So I want to re-paint the whole ceiling.

Comment: Aha. Mold is a problem, and it does seem that killing & covering may not always do the trick. But as a general rule, I would **not** expect scraping paint off drywall to work very consistently.

Comment: Very hard if not impossible to get paint off of drywall/sheetrock, because of the fragility of the paper.  I was able to scrape paint off of a plaster ceiling, but that's a much harder surface than sheetrock.

Answer (score 1):

Gyprock ? Is that a name for Sheetrock? If so moisture above could be a problem even if properly sealed and painted.

The year of construction would be helpful also. Green /blue board are forms of water resistant Sheetrock, as the lighting level is low I cannot tell but it may be green board from my best guess.

Many bathrooms that do not have proper ventilation have issues with ceiling paint even with the best preparation every type of wall board can have issues as the moisture if not exhausted can cause bubbling, mold and many other problems.